# Angular 5 and PHP Cannot POST to a server side file

Tags: php, angular, angular5, vhosts

I trying to send an encrypted variable from angular to php script for some test purposes.

Here is the client side script:

```
ngOnInit(){
let user = "am";
let key = "pizza";
let enc = crypto.AES.encrypt(user, key);
console.log(enc);
let dec = crypto.AES.decrypt(enc, key);
console.log(dec.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));

const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
const params = new HttpParams().set('name', enc)
this.http.post('aff.local/test.php', params, {
    headers: headerOptions
}).subscribe(
        res=>{
            console.log(res)
        },
        error=>{
            console.log( );
        }
    )
}
```

and the test.php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host = "localhost";
$db = "dentist";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};", $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
$enc = $_POST['name'];
echo $enc;
?>
```

I am having the following error in the response:

> POST http://localhost:4200/aff.local/test.php 404 (Not Found)

and in the network tab:

```
Cannot POST /aff.local/test.php
```

The file do exist in the virtual host folder.

Comment: Nothing in the PHP you've provided would cause it to output a 404. We have no way of knowing why your HTTP server is responding with a 404 error for that URL.

Comment: So, how could we help? The port could be wrong, the location `aff.local` could be missing,....

Comment: i need to send it to `aff.local/test.php` and not `http://localhost:4200/aff.local/test.php `

Comment: are you able to access your file(url) via address bar?

Comment: Done. Solution: `http://aff.local/test.php` and not `aff.local/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

POST http: // localhost: 4200 / aff.local / test.php 404 (non trouvé)

**replace server angular(localhost:4200) by server php(ex: wamp: localhost:8080/folder name/filename)

localhost:8080 specifies the directory www of wamp server par defaut .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

If you use just `aff.local/test.php`, angular will treat it as `localhost:4200/yourlink` automatically. 
Just add `http://yourlink` and it is fixed.

So the solution is `http://aff.local/test.php` and not `aff.local/test.php`:

```
ngOnInit(){
   let user = "am";
   let key = "pizza";
   let enc = crypto.AES.encrypt(user, key);
   console.log(enc);
   let dec = crypto.AES.decrypt(enc, key);
   console.log(dec.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));

   const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
   const params = new HttpParams().set('name', enc)
   this.http.post('http://aff.local/test.php', params, {
       headers: headerOptions
  }).subscribe(
        res=>{
            console.log(res)
        },
        error=>{
            console.log( );
        }
    )
}
```